# How to add single quotes around argument in awk print statement?

Tags: escaping, awk

For convenience, I've created an alias to `svn rm` all deleted files in my working copy:

```
alias svnrmall="svn status | grep '^\!' | awk '{print \$2}' | xargs svn rm"
```

This works quite well, except when the filename contains a space character.

An easy solution to the problem seems to be to have `awk` enclose each file path in single quotes, but I'm having difficulty figuring out how to do that.

E.g., something like this (except this results in an error:  "invalid char ''' in expression"):

```
alias svnrmall="... | awk \"{print '\$2'}\" | ..."
```

Comment: PS. no need for `grep`, awk can do pattern matching `awk '/pattern/ {print $2}'` you can do it by field too `awk '$2~/pattern/ {print $2}'`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use -v to define variable `q` and use that variable in awk

```
alias svnrmall="... | awk -v q="'" '{print q $2 q}' | ..."
```

Comment: Marking this as the accepted answer because it correctly solves the problem I described.  However, I am now realizing that I fell victim to [The XY Problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem) – I would actually need to do something like `awk ... {print q $2 $3 (etc.) q}`.

Comment: Note for future readers: you can use `$0` to select the whole line without worrying about the spaces being seperated into fields.

Comment: @Ritesh, what if I want to assign double quote instead of single quote to q? I tried `q="""` but it didn't work...